# How to get Quarter wise sales column in pandas

Tags: pandas

My data frame is below

sales[['Month','Sales2015','Sales2016']]

```
Month   Sales2015   Sales2016
0   Aug 0.00    13208.52
1   Oct 10500.78    23114.91
2   Jun 0.00    6627.00
3   Mar 19881.00    13254.00
```

- How to get Quarter wise sales in 2015 and 2016

Approach is Create Qtr using Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 using numpy.where()

Expected oUt

```
Qtr  2015                                2016
Q1  sum(Jan2015 + Feb2015 + Mar2015) 
Q2  sum(Apr2015 + May2015 + Jun2015) 
Q3  sum(Jul2015 + Aug2015 + Sep2015) 
Q4  sum(Oct2015 + Nov2015 + Dec2015)
```

Since its not date (2011-10-01) i cant use `pd.to_datetime(sales_qtr.Month).dt.quarter`

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format` parameter for datetimes, then [`Series.dt.quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) and add `Q` to `Series` passed to `groupby`:

```
q = 'Q' + pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%b').dt.quarter.rename('Qtr').astype(str)

df = df.groupby(q).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
  Qtr  Sales2015  Sales2016
0  Q1   19881.00   13254.00
1  Q2       0.00    6627.00
2  Q3       0.00   13208.52
3  Q4   10500.78   23114.91
```

Another solution with new column:

```
df['Qtr'] = 'Q' + pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%b').dt.quarter.astype(str)

df = df.groupby('Qtr', as_index=False).sum()
```

Another idea is use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary:

```
d = {'Jan':'Q1', 'Feb':'Q1', 'Mar':'Q1',
     'Apr':'Q2','May':'Q2', 'Jun':'Q2',
     'Jul':'Q3', 'Aug':'Q3', 'Sep':'Q3', 
     'Oct':'Q4', 'Nov':'Q4', 'Dec':'Q4'}

df = df.groupby(df['Month'].map(d).rename('Qtr')).sum().reset_index()
print (df)

  Qtr  Sales2015  Sales2016
0  Q1   19881.00   13254.00
1  Q2       0.00    6627.00
2  Q3       0.00   13208.52
3  Q4   10500.78   23114.91
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sales_qtr = sales[['Month','Sales2015','Sales2016']]
#sales_qtr['Qtr'] = pd.to_datetime(sales_qtr.Month).dt.quarter
d = {'Jan':'Q1', 'Feb':'Q1', 'Mar':'Q1', 'Apr':'Q2', 'May':'Q2','Jun':'Q2', 'Jul':'Q3', 'Aug':'Q3',
     'Sep':'Q3','Oct':'Q4', 'Nov':'Q4', 'Dec':'Q4'}

sales_qtr.Month = sales_qtr.Month.map(d)
```

Comment: if you are looking for np.where wait for better answer